# Append an image to HTML with jQuery, but then replace appended image with new image

Tags: html, jquery, image, replace

I'm trying to display a larger version of an image above a small image gallery when it's clicked.

Currently it keeps appending images without removing the old appended image.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //on click of image
    jQuery("#node-facility-full-group-gallery img").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //get image src
        var imgToDisplay = jQuery(event.target).attr("src");
        //append image to page
        $('<img src="' + imgToDisplay + '">').load(function() {
            $(this).appendTo('#node-facility-full-group-gallery h2');
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: append means add, if you want to clear the element first use `.empty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the previously appended image using ".remove()", to do this you need to give the image an ID when appending it.

Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //on click of image
  jQuery("#node-facility-full-group-gallery img").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // remove prevously appended image
    jQuery('#node-facility-full-group-gallery h2').find('#appendedImg').remove();
    //get image src
    var imgToDisplay = jQuery(event.target).attr("src");
    //append image to page
    $('<img id="appendedImg" src="' + imgToDisplay + '">').load(function() {
      $(this).appendTo('#node-facility-full-group-gallery h2');
    });
  })
});
```